# How to cast a java.lang.String into a java.util.Timer?

Tags: java, string, types, timer

I am reading from a properties file with

> actiontimer = properties.getProperty("action1");

I get a String back, and want to convert this into a timer to use it later in my program.

```
private Timer actiontimer
```

Casting does not work, I get:

> Cannot cast from String to Timer

How can I do this casting?

**UPDATE:**

Formating in the properties file:

> action1:12314

Comment: Casting doesn't work because there is no class relationship between String and Timer. How is `action1` formatted in your properties file?

Comment: its just key:value and I get the numbers back as a String.

Comment: yep, that timer! And I just want to get it from my property file into a Timer Object back.

Comment: What does the string represent? It's not the serialized form, as Timer isn't serializable. Is there any reason you can't just create a new Timer?

Comment: The String represents my Time I use to do a Task. However, right now I cannot use it because its a String. Next I will try to convert it into an Integer and then into a Timer Object... Hope that works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the String to an Integer.

now use the [[Timer's Schedule]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29) passing an int as an argument.

```
   String s = "12314"; 
        Integer delay = Integer.parseInt(s);
        Timer timer = new Timer(); 
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A String is a text representation, while a timer is used for time based  execution of tasks